# Javascript to-do list in which list items are not deleted on clicking the cross button

Tags: javascript

A To-Do list app where pending tasks are added in an ordered list .

Nothing happens on clicking the cross button whereas an onclick delElement() function for the cross button has been defined.

It would be great if someone can point out the mistake.

The HTML and Javascript code is given below-

```js
function newElement() {

  var newli = document.createElement("li");

  var inputValue = document.getElementById("InputText").value;

  var label = document.createElement("label");

  label.innerText = inputValue;

  newli.appendChild(label);

  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

  deleteButton.innerText = "X";

  deleteButton.id = "delete";

  deleteButton.onclick = "delElement()";

  newli.appendChild(deleteButton);

  var PendingTasks = document.getElementById("pending-tasks");

  if (inputValue === '') {

    alert("You must write something!");

  } else {

    PendingTasks.appendChild(newli);

  }

  document.getElementById("InputText").value = "";

}


function delElement() {

  var listItem = this.parentNode;

  var ol = listItem.parentNode;

  ol.removeChild(listItem);

}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="jsfile.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-white text-center">

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold">TO DO</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="InputBox">
  <input type="text" name="NewTask" placeholder="Input a new task" id="InputText">
  <input type="submit" onclick="newElement()" value="Add" class="addbtn">
  <br>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #fffdd0">
  <h2 class="title">Pending Tasks</h2>
  <ol id="pending-tasks">
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be useful to actually come up with the script AND the html, or you are just asking people to guess. Even better, an example people can run.

Comment: @mpm Added! Should I add the CSS code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the **onclick** event function on **deleteButton** as anonymous function does the trick.

**Javascript code:**

```
  function newElement() {

    var newli = document.createElement("li");

    var inputValue = document.getElementById("InputText").value;

    var label = document.createElement("label");

    label.innerText = inputValue;

    newli.appendChild(label);

    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    deleteButton.innerText = "X";

    deleteButton.id = "delete";

    deleteButton.onclick = function() {

      var listItem = this.parentNode;

      var ol = listItem.parentNode;

      ol.removeChild(listItem);
    };
    newli.appendChild(deleteButton);

    var PendingTasks = document.getElementById("pending-tasks");

    if (inputValue === '') {

      alert("You must write something!");

    }

    else {

      PendingTasks.appendChild(newli);

    }

    document.getElementById("InputText").value = "";

  }
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Any explanation as to why the previous function call wasn't working?

Comment: I am guessing the "deleteButton.onclick = 'delElement()';" was assigning the function as string.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Event listener` to the delete button there itself, working example is given below

```js
function newElement() {

  var newli = document.createElement("li");

  var inputValue = document.getElementById("InputText").value;

  var label = document.createElement("label");

  label.innerText = inputValue;

  newli.appendChild(label);

  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

  deleteButton.innerText = "X";

  deleteButton.id = "delete";

  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;

    var ol = listItem.parentNode;

    ol.removeChild(listItem);
  });

  newli.appendChild(deleteButton);

  var PendingTasks = document.getElementById("pending-tasks");

  if (inputValue === '') {

    alert("You must write something!");

  } else {

    PendingTasks.appendChild(newli);

  }

  document.getElementById("InputText").value = "";

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-white text-center">

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold">TO DO</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="InputBox">
  <input type="text" name="NewTask" placeholder="Input a new task" id="InputText">
  <input type="submit" onclick="newElement()" value="Add" class="addbtn">
  <br>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #fffdd0">
  <h2 class="title">Pending Tasks</h2>
  <ol id="pending-tasks">
  </ol>
</div>
```